# How to fix the function single integer as an argument in Racket

Tags: racket

I need some one can explain for me to how to do this please,

divisible-by-7?

Define your own Racket function that takes a single integer as an argument and returns a Boolean that indicates whether the number is evenly divisible by 7. You do not have to perform error checking on the input.

Input: An integer.

Output: A Boolean.

```
Example:

> (divisible-by-7? 14)
#t
> (divisible-by-7? 31)
#f
> (divisible-by-7? 56)
#t
```

this what I have but I keep receiving error

```
(define (divisible-by-7)
(divisible 7))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `divisible` is not a library procedure in racket.

Try

```
(define (divide-by-7? x)
  (= (remainder x 7) 0))
```

Alternatively, if you would like to implement `divisible?` in racket:

```
(define (divisible k)
  (lambda (x)
    (= (remainder x k) 0)))
```

and to use it:

```
(define divide-by-7?
  (divisible 7))
```

Comment: can you please check this for me please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45026005/in-racket-define-a-function-that-takes-two-arguments